# Why is this CSS dropdown disappearing in IE9

Tags: css

On my site: http://www.carbonfibergear.com/ if you hover over the "SHOP" menu it shows a dropdown list based on [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/).  I noticed in IE9, once you move the mouse off the word shop, the dropdown disappears.  Any idea how I can fix this?

There are some updates to this question which you can see in this answer (please read through the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622168/1464510

Comment: i dont have ie9. so cant test but nice website.

Comment: This menu works fine in IE9 standards mode.  It appears to be IE9 in quirks mode that causes the problem.  I've not dug deeper but in quicks mode, the "shop" menu item doesn't appear to have a hover area.

Answer (score 1):

looks like a gap between your button and the menu that IE doesnt like.. it is assuming that you are mousing off the button.. if you move ninja fast, you can keep the menu focused.

Change:

```
header nav #nav-site li {
margin: 0 10px 3px 0;
}
```

To:

```
header nav #nav-site li {
padding: 0 10px 3px 0;
}
```

see if that helps.. IE acts weird when calculating overall box size including margins.

Comment: I see what you mean, and tried to change the margin to padding locally, but that didn't seem to do it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I think it has to do with the margin on header nav .dropdown_1column .mainbox   I'm playing around with it now, but you sparked the idea :)

Comment: I was able to get it working makeshift for now, but I can't get it so the spacing lines up with the bottom border of the header without having the issue.  For now this will work, but any idea how to get that spacing while resolving the issue in IE?

Comment: sorry for the delay.. was out to lunch.. it does look like the `.dropdown_1column .mainbox` is the culprit.. IE is weird about margins on dropdown menus.. maybe take the margin out, add the top border (same size as the image rotator, ~4px). that should butt the elements together. kind of hard to see what could/should work without actually getting in there and hacking away..